# Javascript function: Append string to object and return object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I need to get either the X position or the Y position of a mousedown event. 
So I tried passing a parameter to my getPosition function.

```
function getPosition(event, param) {
  // expected: var value = event.pageX;
  var value = event.param;
  return value;
}

$('#element').on('mousedown', function(e){
  var myValue = getPosition(e, 'pageX');
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation instead:

```
function getPosition(event, param) {
  // expected: var value = event.pageX;
  var value = event[param];
  return value;
}
```

If you use dot notation, the browser will look for a property called `param` on the `event` object, which doesn't exist. Using bracket notation, the browser will evaluate `param` and look for that on the object.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/frgfQ/) is a fiddle which demonstrates the code above.

Comment: This works! 

Performance-wise, are there any drawbacks to this approach as opposed to using two separate functions getPositionX and getPositionY ?

Comment: Performance-wise, bracket notation seems to be slightly slower. But you'd be doing well to even measure the difference between the two without calling it millions of times sequentially. http://jsperf.com/dot-vs-square-bracket/5